# Return matched input from an elasticsearch query as they were typed

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is an example:

```JSON
"query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
               {
                   "match_phrase_prefix": {
                       "keyword":{
                           "query": "pokemno", //approximative term
                           "fuzziness": 1
                       }
                   }
               },
               //... multiple should closures there
            ]
        }
    }
```

This query match a document with the  ***"Pokémon"*** keyword, however i want to get back **the exact input search term(s)** that has matched for each document (here, ***"pokemno"***).

AFAIK the highlight feature only return the matched values as they are saved in the document, but not the ones from the search input.

Is there any way to get those values back from the search?

Comment: If I understood, you just need to change your query to use `match_phrase` instead of `match_phrase_prefix`?

Comment: @JosuéZatarain Well... Yeah it would work but that's not the idea... ^^
I don't want my query to be strict, i want to know which approximative search term(s) from the input has matched.

Comment: So.. you can add both queries in the same should clause.